# How can I force a Mongoose Save() call to be synchronous

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am writing a script in Node.js which needs to do the following:

1. Open XML file
2. For each node in file
3. Do a mongodb lookup to try find object relating to this node
4. if object not found, create it, otherwise manipulate the found object in some manner
5. save the (possibly new) object back to the database.
6. goto step 2

I have looked at this for some time and come to the conclusion that it is almost impossible to do this with asynchronous mongodb. The problems are multiple, but for example if you are dealing with 20,000 of these nodes then doing it async will hang the script. However doing them as a batch insert isn't feasible either due to step 4 needing to look if the object already exists or not.

It would be possible to cobble something horrible together which caches the created objects and then saves them as something like step 7, except it would be difficult because there are multiple collections that the objects are going into, and you would need to try look up objects from the cache first, then the database, at step 4. If that is the solution then I will just write off Javascript as broken and write this in perl instead. So my question is this, for something so simple as the above sequence of actions, can I somehow **force** mongodb to be synchronous so that my script doesn't turn into insanity? I want to be able to say document.save() (I'm using Mongoose by the way) and then have it not return until after it has actually saved.

**Edit: Added code**

This is called from a loop roughly 20000 times. I don't care (within reason) how long it takes, but 200,000 async calls to save hangs the script so it can't be that (it also uses over 1.5gig of ram at that point). If I cannot make *hObj.save();* wait until the object is actually saved then I am going to need to write this in a more capable language.

```
    models('hs').findOne({name: r2.$.name}, function (err, h) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        var resultObj = createResult(meeting, r1, r2);

        if (h == undefined) {

            var hObj = new models('hs')({
                name : r2.$.name,
                results : [resultObj],
                numResults : 1
            });

            hObj.save();
        } else {
            h.results.push(resultObj);
            h.numResults++;
            h.save();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but rather than go totally synchronous you might re-think your process when there are libraries such as [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) available, which would allow you to do certain actions in sequence. Not really an answer without some code in your question to apply an example to.

Comment: Try looking to [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).  Also, you may employ some streaming solution to read your XML to integrate with it nicely.

Comment: I did look at async, but it didnt seem to have a way to say "call this function and dont return until after its callback has executed". Am I mistaken?

Comment: You are mistaken. `async.series`, `async.parallelLimit`, `async.eachLimit` all serialize execution.

Comment: I'd love to see how I can use async.series in the above code to make save() synchronous. I may well be mistaken - there are not a lot of simple examples of async on their documentation, only a range of complex ones.

Comment: looking over the async documentation again makes me think that I was right - async will not do what I want. It will let me execute multiple functions in series, but in my case thats no better than executing them individually. I need a way to say: h.save() (execution wont proceed to next line until save is complete)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [async github](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) page:

> **eachSeries**(arr, iterator, callback)
>
> The same as each, only iterator is applied to each item in arr in
>   series. The next iterator is only called once the current one has
>   completed. This means the iterator functions will complete in order.

So assuming you have your XML nodes in *nodes*

```
async.eachSeries(
  nodes,
  // This will be applied to every node in nodes
  function (node, callback) {
    models('hs').findOne({name: r2.$.name}, function (err, h) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        // Async?
        var resultObj = createResult(meeting, r1, r2);

        if (h == undefined) {

          var hObj = new models('hs')({
            name : r2.$.name,
            results : [resultObj],
            numResults : 1
          });

          hObj.save(function (err, p) {
            // Callback will tell async that you are done
            callback();
          });
        } else {
          h.results.push(resultObj);
          h.numResults++;
          h.save(function (err, p) {
            // Callback will tell async that you are done
            callback();
          });
        }
      }
    });
  },
  // This will be executed when all nodes has been processed
  function (err) {
    console.log('done!');
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is right. I ended up using a combination of async.eachSeries() & async.series, and with a bit of rework everything works great. I think part of the problem was I had so many functions calling each other, that I didn't see how to get the final save linked back to the forEach at the upper level.